# Who are some of the figures shown in photographs in the Whips' room in the 1968 film If...?

Tags: if

One of the locations in the 1968 film *If...* is the room used by the Whips, or school prefects.

The scene I am especially thinking of is the [one in which Mick Travis and two friends report to the Whips and they are told they must be punished](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqoGcC4S5jk). Several photographs are shown, including one at the top right of the noticeboard next to the door through which Mick and friends come in. The man in the photograph rings a bell with me, probably as a politician, but I have not yet identified him.

Who is this man? And who are the other figures shown in photographs in the Whips' room?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - Many thanks for editing the tag. Is it possible to change it to *If...*, with the ellipsis? That is the correct name of the film and is bound to be clearer for many readers.

Comment: It might be technically possible. But generally we don't really do punctuation in tags. The fact that tags might not represent titles *exactly* is an issue we just have to live with for many other reasons anyway. I acknowledge that this specific example is quite a bit short indeed, though.